# React Navigation annotating useNavigator with BottomTabs

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Can anybody help with typing / annotating `useNavigator` with RootStack -> Tabs -> Each tab has a stack setup.

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import type {
  CompositeScreenProps,
  NavigatorScreenParams,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import type { BottomTabScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeTabParamList>;
};

export type RootStackScreenProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, T>;

export type HomeTabParamList = {
  Dashboard: undefined;
  Map: undefined;
};

export type HomeTabScreenProps<T extends keyof HomeTabParamList> =
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<HomeTabParamList, T>,
    RootStackScreenProps<keyof RootStackParamList>
  >;

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}

export default () =>
  useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();
```

```js
const navigation = useNavigator()
navigation.navigate('Dashboard') // Throws type error, only 'Home' is a suggestion.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use it like this:

```js
navigation.navigate('Home', { screen: 'Dashboard' })
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

You also don't need the `export default () => useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();`. If you import `useNavigation` from `@react-navigation/native`, it will have the correct type.

Comment: Do I not need to annotate useNavigator because of the global namespace I added? Now that I think of it, it didn't work before I added that.

Comment: No you don't, given you're on latest version of React Navigation